# What animal is the mascot of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Linux has Penguins, GitHub has weird cats and I think even Minix has a raccoon!

I think it is long due that [Pangolin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangolin) got to be a mascot! Not yet a Penguin, but close. What say you? (Sorry advance if Stack Overflow already has a mascot and I am being stupid.)

EDIT:
Oh, got what have I done! Forgive me! I didn't know better!

Comment: I'd say the unofficial mascot is already a Unicorn.

Comment: Why a pangolin by the way? Just because it shares a lot of letters with penguin?

Comment: Saw it on lastweektonight https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5d3nASKtGas the wabble part made my heart melt as I associated it with a penguin. It will get its chance someday.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unicorn. Unicorn. Unicorn. Unicorn. [Unicorn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uipTZ2re4Uk).

Comment: I wonder if this is the first question where the correct answer was five * unicorn. Again, forgive me.

Comment: @user1235831 - Nope. 5 * unicorn pretty much works everywhere.

Answer (score 13):

With all due respect to my colleague, I think we all know which *real* animal best represents the tough, persistent, no-nonsense attitude of Stack Overflow:

[image: Honey Badger]

[image: Honey Badger don't care]

Comment: "tough, presistent, no-nonsense", <- Wow, that was not an ironic sentiment. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iksnk1YVkac